# Executar procedure SQL que desabilita datas no Datepicker

Tags: sql-server, datepicker

Tenho um sistema com um datepicker, e quero que algumas datas sejam desabilitadas automaticamente.
Essas datas devem popular automaticamente o array que desabilita as datas. 
(Hoje está manual como mostra a função abaixo)

```
var disableddates = ["10-12-2015", "11-20-2015", "12-21-2015", "12-22-2015", "12-23-2015", "12-24-2015", "12-25-2015", "12-28-2015", "12-29-2015", "12-30-2015", "12-31-2015", "1-1-2016"];
```

Tenho uma procedure SQL Server que traz uma lista com todas essas datas.
Como chamá-la antes de chamar o datepicker desabilitando essas datas?

Comment: Qual a plataforma (linguagem) você está desenvolvendo? Você pode fazer a solicitação das datas por AJAX.

Comment: O sistema foi desenvolvido em ASP Classico. Não tenho ideia de como fazer essa solicitação com o AJAX. Poderia me dar algumas dicas por favor?

Answer (score 0):

Fiz uma chamada para a procedure antes da chamada para a função de desabilitar datas, e passei o resultado por variável, com as datas concatenadas e formatadas da forma que entra no datepicker:
var disableddates = <%=vardatasfim %>

A variável vardisableddates é utilizada na função para bloquear fim de semana, e utilizada como parâmetro na beforeShowDay.